# Rendering variants for 'Page Content' SXA rendering not showing

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

I have added a few `Rendering Variants` for the `SXA` rendering `Page Content` (SS below)

[image]

But, when I try to use this rendering on the page from the `Experience Editor` the dropdown for the `Rendering Variant` is not visible.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rebuild indexes and especially sxa master index one.

Works for me without trouble.

I have added second one to test:

[image]

and it's shown properly in EE:

[image]

You should see it also in Edit style dialog:

[image]

Comment: I never thought that it would require a simple rebuild click. Thank you so much anyways. :)

Comment: I did rebuild the indexes still facing same issue.. anything else to change or update?

Comment: After a rebuild, it still didnt work. I added another test rendering variant. All items started showing.. Thanks :)